# how exactly does CUDA handle a memory access?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

i would like to know how CUDA hardware/run-time system handles the following case.

If a warp (warp1 in the following) instruction involves access to global memory (load/store); the run-time system schedules the next ready warp for execution.

When the new warp is executed,

1. Will the "memory access" of warp1 be conducted in parallel, i.e. while the new warp is running ?
2. Will the run time system put warp1 into a memory access waiting queue; once the  memory request is completed, the warp is then moved into the runnable queue?
3. Will the instruction pointer related to warp1 execution be incremented automatically and in parallel to the new warp execution, to annotate that the memory request is completed?

For instance, consider this pseudo code `output=input+array[i];` where `output` and `input` are both scalar variables mapped into registers, whereas `array` is saved in the global memory.

To run the above instruction, we need to load the value of `array[i]` into a (temporary) register before updating output; i.e the above instruction can be translated into 2 macro assembly instructions load reg, `reg=&array[i]`, `output_register=input_register+reg`.

I would like to know how the hardware and runtime system handle the execution of the above 2 macro assembly instructions, given that load can't return immediately

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand your questions correctly, so I'll just try to answer them as I read them:

1. Yes, while a memory transaction is in flight further independent instructions will continue to be issued. There isn't necessarily a switch to a different warp though - while instructions from other warps will always be independent, the following instructions from the same warp might be independent as well and the same warp may keep running (i.e. further instructions may be issued from the same warp).
2. No. As explained under 1. the warp can and will continue executing instructions until either the result of the load is needed by dependent instruction, or a memory fence /  barrier instruction requires it to wait for the effect of the store being visible to other threads.
   This can go as far as issuing further (independent) load or store instructions, so that multiple memory transactions can be in flight for the same warp at the same time. So the status of a warp after issuing a load/store doesn't change fundamentally and it is not halted until necessary.
3. The instruction pointer will always be incremented automatically (there is no situation where you ever do this manually, nor are there instructions allowing to do so). However, as 2. implies, this doesn't necessarily indicate that the memory access has been performed - there is separate hardware to track progress of memory accesses.

Please note that the hardware implementation is completely undocumented by Nvidia. You might find some indications of possible implementations if you search through Nvidia's patent applications.

GPUs up to the Fermi generation (compute capability 2.x) tracked outstanding memory transaction completely in hardware. While undocumented by Nvidia, the common mechanism to track (memory) transactions in flight is [scoreboarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoreboarding).

GPUs from newer generations starting with Kepler (compute capability 3.x) use some assistance in the form of control words embedded in the shader assembly code. While again undocumented, Scott Gray has reversed engineered these for his [Maxas](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas) Maxwell assembler. He found that (amongst other things) the control words contain barrier instructions for tracking memory transactions and was kind enough to document his findings on his [Control-Codes](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas/wiki/Control-Codes) wiki page.

Comment: thank you for your reply and sorry for not making my questions clearer. I would like to know more about " the separate hardware to track progress of memory accesses." you referred to in  your answer . I've updated my original query as advised.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the changed questions.

Comment: Thank you, Tera, all understood. I've a further question  re. the LDST cores in the SMX, do theyt only calculate the effective address to fetch? can they be used to do fixed point arithmetic  addition and subtraction?

Comment: According to their [SASS instruction list](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#maxwell-pascal), Maxwell and Pascal have a `LEA` "load effective address" instructions. As it is not exposed in PTX though, you'll have to experiment to see if and how it can be generated.

Comment: Given it's undocumented status it's not clear what it is good for, if it can be generated with the current toolchain. I'd speculate the `LEA` instruction might be helpful if you want to add a 32-bit integer to a 64 bit integer in a single instruction.